# Bootstrap Glyphicons not appearing for carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

For my carousel, the bootstrap glyphicons are not showing up. I made sure that I have the fonts folder.

You can see a test version of the site here (redacted).

Interestingly enough, the arrows appear only when I do a live preview with my web IDE (Brackets by Adobe).

Comment: The glyphicons are showing for me on your test site. Could it be caching for you? Maybe ctrl+f5 to refresh?

Comment: @Steve nothing, just used a different browser and my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Problem is the bootstrap.css file url is src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot)

**../ indicates root domain.**

CSS is pointing to the following URL:
http://thesabreslicer.site.nfoservers.com/fonts/

Your folder is located at:
http://thesabreslicer.site.nfoservers.com/**thesabreslicer/dw/fonts**/

*Move the font folder to the root and it will resolve your issue.*